# Adding a Background Process to my Windows Phone app

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, cordova, windows-phone, background-process

I have a Windows Phone Phonegap/Cordova App that is running a WinJS process thread. However, this really needs to run on app initialisation and in the background - polling on an interval.

What I basically want to do is have a PhoneGap app which executes an AJAX call as a background process to keep files up to date as they are sent from a server.

```
setInterval(function() {
    // Check data with $.ajax();
}, 30000);
```

I have been tearing my hair out with this one, I've tried so much code my brain is fried. I'm sure it must be possible, but I cannot figure out how to run an AJAX call as a Background Service...

Pre-emptive "cheers for the help guys and girls"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update some information when the App starts and everytime a timer runs out. Is it right?

**I would do this way:**

```
function yourMainFunction(){
    try{
        if(localStorage){

            //A flag that indicates if it is App Instalation (First Use) or Not
            if(!localStorage.appRunFirstTime){
                callLoadingStructure();

                //Assuming that you data file is a TXT file and we have a JSON Structure inside it
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'text',
                        url: 'yourSite/yourData.txt',
                        success: function (data) {
                            var content = JSON.parse(data);

                            //The JSON parsed DATA
                            doWhateverYouNeedWithTheData(content);//This method should use the data from your server
                            localStorage.setItem("appRunFirstTime", "OK!!!");
                            closeLoadingStructure();
                        }
                        error: function(errowThrown){
                            console.log(errowThrown);
                        }
                    });

                //Minimun timeout to show Loading Structure even if the request works without any lag
                }, 1000);
            }
            //App is already instaled
            else{
                setInterval(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'text',
                        url: 'yourSite/yourData.txt',
                        success: function (data) {
                            var content = JSON.parse(data);

                            //The JSON parsed DATA
                            doWhateverYouNeedWithTheData(content);
                            //updateDOM?(); if you need to update the DOM when new information comes up
                        }
                        error: function(errowThrown){
                            console.log(errowThrown);
                        }
                    });

                //Minimun timeout to show Loading Structure even if the request works without any lag
                }, 30000);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}

function callLoadingStructure(){
    //Its a example of a loading structure while the first content loads
    document.getElementById("yourMainContentDiv").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("yourLoadingDiv").style.display = "block";
}

function closeLoadingStructure(){
    //Cloasing loading structure and showing maindiv
    document.getElementById("yourMainContentDiv").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("yourLoadingDiv").style.display = "none";
}
```

Hope it helps. Best regards!

Comment: This doesn't work for me, but I'm accepting it because I want to delete the question - you can have the bounty.